# How can I attach to process automatically without having to search it everytime in Rider?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2022, jetbrains-rider

In Visual Studio I have settings to attach automatically to a local process:

[image]

So, when I click the selected button, it will automatically build the code and attach to the running local process specified in properties->configuration properties->debugging->Command

Now I'm trying to do the same setup in Rider, so I can build + debug with 1 click without having to build, attach to, search process in list, then attach.

[image]

I was trying to create a config for it but I just don't see how to do it:

[image]

How can I recreate the same setup (or most similar) I have in Visual Studio?

Comment: I have this same question - did you find an answer?

Comment: Nop. I don't think there is a way to solve this as of the time being.

Comment: Does anyone solve this problem?

Comment: If you have a way of obtaining the pid, you can launch rider from the command line. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Working_with_the_IDE_Features_from_Command_Line.html#arguments

Answer (score 1):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Attaching_to_Local_Process.html#reattach-to-process

> You can attach again to the very last process that you have attached
> to, even without opening the dialog. To do so, press ⌘+⌥+⇧+F5 or
> choose Run | Reattach to Process from the main menu.

To make this easier you can add this command to your main menu and use it instead of the default Run or Debug commands.

[image]

You will need to attach to the process once manually though.